Weird behavior dealing with c++ std::variant comparison and operator functions
I have been trying to make a game in Visual Studio using c++17, and I created a class type called ErrorType to represent all the error numeric values (nan, inf, etc). By using std::variant<long double, ErrorType>, I can now store any value and check if the value is an error.
However, the problem comes when I try to compare two std::variant<long double, ErrorType>s and the compiler sends an error as follows:
call to object of class type 'std::not_equal_to<void>': no matching call operator found
Here's the minimum reproducible code:
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
namespace Q
{
    struct ErrorType {};
} using namespace Q;

bool operator!= (ErrorType a, ErrorType b) { return false; }

signed main()
{
    std::variant<double, ErrorType> a, b;
    a = 1.0, b = 2.0;
    std::cout << (a != b); // Error!
}

The code above took me one hour to fix. Here's how I fixed it:
As you can see, I used a namespace to store the ErrorType. So, I moved the struct out of the namespace. And guess what? It now compiles (yes, you can try it yourself). See Below:
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct ErrorType {};
bool operator!= (ErrorType a, ErrorType b) { return false; }

signed main()
{
    std::variant<double, ErrorType> a, b;
    a = 1.0, b = 2.0;
    std::cout << (a != b); // Compiles fine now!
}

I am perplexed about this weird behavior. Can anyone please explain why? Any sort of help is welcome.

Don't do using namespace Q;, and put the comparison operator inside the namespace. And read up on argument-dependent lookup (ADL).

And for the future, please try to copy-paste more, preferably the whole, build-log into your questions. There could be notes and information that could help solving the problem.

Side note, looks like you could also use std::expected (C++23)

Yeah, that is also an option, but sadly, I think it's still unavailable on my compiler.

I am perplexed about this weird behavior.  This is normal and expected ADL behavior.
